# Axon: How to configure amqp publishing for single events?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amqp, spring-amqp, axon

I have a simple spring-driven service which publishes events via amqp.
The configuration is based on [bootiful-axon](https://github.com/abuijze/bootiful-axon).

Now I want the service to maintain some private state. It is a simple use case that can be realized with 3 extra events. Those events have no meaning outside the service's scope so I don't want them to "leave".

How can I specify which events should be published via amqp and which not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

Custom `SpringAMQPPublisher` that intercepts the `send` method:

```
public class SelectiveAmqpPublisher extends SpringAMQPPublisher {


    static boolean shouldSend (Class<?> pt) {
        return PublicEvent.class.isAssignableFrom(pt);
    }


    public SelectiveAmqpPublisher (
            SubscribableMessageSource<EventMessage<?>> messageSource) {

        super(messageSource);

    }


    @Override
    protected void send (List<? extends EventMessage<?>> events) {

        super.send(events.stream()
                        .filter(e -> shouldSend(e.getPayloadType()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    }    

}
```

Configuration:

```
@Autowired
private AMQPProperties amqpProperties;

@Autowired 
private RoutingKeyResolver routingKeyResolver;

@Autowired
private AMQPMessageConverter aMQPMessageConverter;


@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "shutDown")
public SpringAMQPPublisher amqpBridge(
             EventBus eventBus, 
             ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
             AMQPMessageConverter amqpMessageConverter) {

    SpringAMQPPublisher publisher = new SelectiveAmqpPublisher(eventBus);



    // The rest is from axon-spring-autoconfigure...

    publisher.setExchangeName(amqpProperties.getExchange());
    publisher.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    publisher.setMessageConverter(amqpMessageConverter);
    switch (amqpProperties.getTransactionMode()) {

        case TRANSACTIONAL:
            publisher.setTransactional(true);
            break;
        case PUBLISHER_ACK:
            publisher.setWaitForPublisherAck(true);
            break;
        case NONE:
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("....");
    }

    return publisher;

}
```